# Images showing as just text in preview VUE 3 (typescript)

Tags: typescript, npm, vuejs3

I'm working on a Portfolio site. I've come into an issue with my site. Everything works perfectly fine when I run it through `npm run dev` but once I do `npm run preview` some of the images do not work. These images are in the files called `3dModellingFiles.ts` and then gets displayed in `3dModelling.vue`.

As said, it works in the dev but not the preview. On the preview side it just shows as text: `../src/components/Software/3dModelling/Files/Images/2023/Badge_Stand_(27_11_2023).png`

Vue.js

```
<script setup lan="ts">
...
import { twenty_three, twenty_twenty } from "@/components/Software/3dModelling/Files/3dModellingFiles"
...
</script>

<template>
...
<h2 id="year-2020" class="text-pf-red-300 text-3xl underline font-arial font-bold mt-10">2020</h2>
        <div v-for="twentyTwenty in twenty_twenty" :key="twentyTwenty.id.value" :id="'year-' + twentyTwenty.date.getFullYear()">
          <div class="bg-pf-red-950 bg-opacity-10 p-2 my-5 rounded hover:bg-opacity-30 flex">
            <div class="m-2 mr-5 flex-shrink-0">
              <img class="rounded"
                :src="twentyTwenty.image"
                :alt="twentyTwenty.image"
                style="width: 350px; object-fit: cover;">
            </div>
            <div class="flex flex-col">
              <div>
                <h1 class="text-white text-2xl font-arial font-bold mt-2">{{ twentyTwenty.title }}</h1>
                <h1 class="text-woodsmoke-300 text-md font-arial">{{ twentyTwenty.date.toLocaleDateString('en-GB') }}</h1>
              </div>
              <h1 class="text-white text-lg font-arial mt-4">{{ twentyTwenty.description }}</h1>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
...
</template>
```

3dModellingFiles.ts

```
import {ref} from 'vue';
export const twenty_three = [
    {
        id: ref(1),
        title: "Badge Stand",
        description: "Description Text",
        date: new Date("2023-11-27"),
        image: "../src/components/Software/3dModelling/Files/Images/2023/Badge_Stand_(27_11_2023).png"
    },
]
```

What am I doing wrong?

*EXTRA NOTE - NOT MY QUESTION*

I've tried some other changes on another page by doing it like `./components/`  which gives me a get 404 error in the console log

```
DecafMechanics.png:1    
       GET http://localhost:4173/components/Software/Projects/Files/Images/2023/DecafMechanics.png
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want dynamically use image like :src="image" form your static folder,the variable "image" need use import in vue3,or use require() in vue2

```js
import {
  ref
} from 'vue';
import image from '@/src/components/Software/3dModelling/Files/Images/2023/Badge_Stand_(27_11_2023).png'
export const twenty_three = [{
      id: ref(1),
      title: "Badge Stand",
      description: "Description Text",
      date: new Date("2023-11-27"),
      image
    ]
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Although I made a minor change. instead of calling it:
`import image from '@/components/Software/3dModelling/Files/Images/2023/Badge_Stand_(27_11_2023).png';`
I went for:
`import badgeStand from '@/components/Software/3dModelling/Files/Images/2023/Badge_Stand_(27_11_2023).png';`

I also made it so it'll say `image: badgeStand`

Just wished there was a way without needing the import for the images. But it is what it is.

Thank you anyway :)